# How much choice is needed to prove that $|G| \nless |G/ \sim|$ for any equivalence relation $\sim$ on set $G$?

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations, axiom-of-choice

$G/ \sim$ is the set of $\sim$-equivalence classes in $G$ and $|G/ \sim|$ is the cardinality of $G/ \sim$. $|A| \leq |B|$ means that there is an injective function from $A$ to $B$. $|A| < |B|$ means that $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|A| \neq |B|$.

If $\pi:G \to G/ \sim$ is defined by $\pi (x) = [x]_{\sim}$, then $\pi$ has an injective right inverse $h:G/ \sim \to G$ (by the Axiom of Choice) and $|G/ \sim| \leq |G|$ and $|G| \nless |G/ \sim|$

Is the full axiom of choice needed to prove that $|G| \nless |G/ \sim|$ (just that one part, not necessarily both of $|G/ \sim| \leq |G|$ and $|G| \nless |G/ \sim|$)? If not, what is the weakest form of choice that is needed to prove it?

If the restriction that "$G$ is a group, $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $\sim$ is defined by $x \sim y$ iff $x y^{-1} \in N$" was added, does that change the answer?

Comment: I think the tag #set-theory must be replaced by #elementary-set-theory

Comment: The #set-theory tag is correct, in my view.

Comment: Well, if $|G/{\sim}| \leq |G|$, then $|G| \not< |G/{\sim}|$, for otherwise, by transitivity, we'd have $|G/{\sim}| < |G/{\sim}|$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as the **Weak Partition Principle**. We don't know all too much about it, but it implies there are no-measurable sets of reals and there are no infinite Dedekind-finite sets.